# AngularJS: Is there a way to create two-way binding on a label element so that I can dynamically attach it to an object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, data-binding

This problem has been frustrating me for the last couple days now so, here I am. I'll try to be as clear as possible.

I have an object to retrieve from the database. This object is used to create dropdown menus. It has two properties on it: A section property, which contains one string. The other property is called value, which contains all the possible options that the user can select in the dropdown. I use two nested ng-repeats in my `HTML` to create the dropdowns.

I am trying to send out to the database a `formData` object that has 2 properties in it: the name of the dropdown menu, and the value that the user selected. Appending the value selected from the dropdown menu is easy thanks to two way data binding that I set on the select element. However, I CANNOT figure out how to grab the value from the label element inside my controller so that I can attach it to my formData object. As far as I know, `ng-model` does not work on a label element. Here is the `HTML`, which hopefully will make it a bit more clear:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" ng-controller="PreferenceCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(name, section) in configs">
        <label ng-bind="name"></label>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="formData.settings[$index].value">
            <option value="" disabled="disabled">---Please Select Option---</option>
            <option ng-repeat="item in section" value="{{item.value}}" ng-bind="item.value">
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" ng-include="gametemp"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
        <div class="text-center col-md-12 padding-15">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="saveSetting()" formnovalidate translate>
                <i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin' ng-if="showBusy"></i>&nbsp;Save
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Because the `<select>` class can have an `ng-model` attached to it, I can easily capture that value in my controller. I cannot do the same with the label. If anyone can help me out I will forever be your best friend. Thank you!

Comment: Are you just trying to display the selected value in the label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your question title "Is there a way to create a two-way binding on a label element", no, that isn't possible.

But if I understand correctly what you're trying to do, it sounds like you want to save data to the database based on information contained in both the `<label>` and it's associated `<select>`.  If that's true, then I'd recommend using an `ng-change` function in your `<select>` like this:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="formData.settings[$index].value" ng-click="dropdownItemClicked(name, formData.settings[$index].value)">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled">---Please Select Option---</option>
    <option ng-repeat="item in section" value="{{item.value}}" ng-bind="item.value">
    </option>
</select>
```

In your controller, create a function to handle this `ng-click` event:

```
$scope.dropdownItemClicked = function(name, value) {
    console.log(name, value);
    // save name/value to database
}
```

The key is to pass in the exact data you want to save to the database into your `dropdownItemClicked()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just put the value inside the label?

```
<label ng-bind="name">{{formData.settings[$index].value}}</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to read from the label. It is the **one** way binding after all, right. I would do something like this.

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.formData = {
        settings:[]
    };

    $scope.configs = {
        'Label1': [{ value: 11 }, { value: 12 }],
        'Label2': [{ value: 21 }, { value: 22 }]
    };
    
    $scope.change = function(name, idx) {
        $scope.formData.settings[idx].name = name;
    };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
<form class="form-horizontal" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(name, section) in configs">
        <label ng-bind="name"></label>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="formData.settings[$index].value" ng-change="change(name, $index)">
            <option value="" disabled="disabled">---Please Select Option---</option>
            <option ng-repeat="item in section" value="{{item.value}}" ng-bind="item.value">
            {{item.name}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" ng-include="gametemp"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
        <div class="text-center col-md-12 padding-15">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="saveSetting()" formnovalidate translate>
                <i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin' ng-if="showBusy"></i>&nbsp;Save
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
    {{formData.settings}}
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```